# Need help improving my regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a text file, where I have say these three lines of text.

```
.....03122      25   8.2  "'Allo 'Allo!" (1982) {Fleeing Monks (#7.3)}
0.1.1.2003      15   5.6  "$weepstake$" (1979)
0..0012101      45   6.6  "$#*! My Dad Says" (2010) {Make a Wish (#1.9)}
```

I want to extract only the following.

```
8.2  "'Allo 'Allo!" (1982)
5.6  "$weepstake$" (1979)
6.6  "$#*! My Dad Says" (2010)
```

I tried using scanner in Java and it failed. I also tried splitting the string using tab spaces. It looks like there are some unevenly spaced tabs.

I though it would be easy to get these three values using Regex. This is what I was able to write so far. Could someone help me out.

```
\\d\\.\\d
```

Comment: First, you can use substring to cut out the part from 8.2 etc. Then use regex to further process it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this regex `\d+\.\d+\s+".+?"\s+\(\d+?\)`

for grouping use this one `(\d+\.\d+)\s+"(.+?)"\s+\((\d+?)\)`

```
8.2          - 1 group
'Allo 'Allo! - 2 group
1982         - 3 group
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's one right answer, it kind of depends on the exact nature of the data, but I'd suggest something like this:

```
 [0-9.]+\s+\d+\s+(\d\.\d\s+.*" \(\d\d\d\d\))
```

You'll want to capture the stuff inside the ().

That means match digits/dot, followed by 1 or more whitespace, followed by digits, followed by 1 or more white space.  Then inside the actual match, digit, dot, digit, 1 or more whitespace, quote, space, literal (, 4 digits, and literal ).